# RegEx for word boundary but still match if is preceded or followed by special chars

Tags: regex

What I want to accomplish is to match any word even if they are followed or preceded by non-alphanumeric characters.

So for example for the following string `This string contains word1 and word2* and anotherword1`, I would like to get two matches for `word1` and `word2` but not `anotherword1` nor `word1` in the `anotherword1`.

What I have right now is

`\b(word1|word2)\b`

but this will not match for `word2` (ignoring the *).

From what I read `\b` only matches between an alphanumeric character and a non-alphanumeric character but I have no idea how to handle this special chars trailing my targeted words.

LE: I think `(?i)(?<=^|[^a-zA-Z0-9])(word1|word2)(?=$|[^a-zA-Z0-9])` does the trick ... but does it look ok? Is it a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: Why not simply remove `\b`

Comment: Could you explain? [This `\b(word1|word2)\b` regex matches `word1` and `word2`](https://regex101.com/r/yB6bM9/1) as you expect.

Comment: `word2` will not be matched if for it will be followed by a comma. Edited my answer to make it clear. Hope I nailed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for

```
(?<!\w)(word1|word2)(?!\w)
```

The `(?<!\w)` and `(?!\w)` lookarounds are *unambiguous* leading (`(?<!\w)`) and trailing (`(?!\w)`) word boundaries.

The `\b` construct meaning depends on the context: `\bw` will match a `w` in `*w` as it will require a non-word character before `\b`, but `\b\*` will require a word character before `*` as `*` is a non-word character.

In languages that do not support lookbehinds, the `(?<!\w)` should be replaced with `(^|\W)` and further manipulations should be done in the code.